# Indent changes when using CoC, how do I stop this?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, indentation, autocompletion, plugin-coc

I have set up my init.vim file to always use tabs as indentation by adding this to it:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set noexpandtab
```

Ever since I installed CoC to use Rust's language server, it indents with four spaces instead of tabs, overriding my init.vim. Whenever I open a file I have to run `set noexpandtab`, and if I have forgotten to do this I have to also run `%retab!` to fix any indentations that were made with spaces. I tried moving my tab configuration in init.vim to its very end thinking that this was probably some code in CoC that runs when the program starts, so I would override it with my config, but this didn't work.

How can I stop this?

Comment: Might be `coc-prettier` if you installed it, which formats documents automatically. Or maybe put `set noexpandtab` in `vim/after/ftplugin/rust.vim`.

Comment: This worked! Is there a way to set this for every type of file, not just rust files? Also, do you mind posting this as an answer so i can set it as the accepted answer?

Comment: I'll do that soon as I can! You can add as many files as you need there, e.g `c.vim`, `vim.vim`, for each filetype.

Comment: @Biggybi don't forget `:setlocal`, and maybe mention `b:undo_ftplugin`. Might even be a case for `~/.vim/after/indent/rust.vim`, with corresponding `b:undo_indent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim loads multiple files as described in `:h :runtimepath`.

In `ftplugin/`, you can add files like `rust.vim` where you define options for this filetype only.
You may need to put the config in `after/ftplugin` to overwrite options set by other config files.

Considering this, a basic approach for your problem is to drop everything you rust-specific config in `after/ftplugin/rust.vim`.

However, you can go further and use `(after/)indent/`, `(after/)compiler/` and so on, to organize your config even more.

Note that the options you set are not automatically restored. This can be a problem when the buffer's filetype changes: an option set for the first filetype will be preserved if it's not set for the second.

To avoid this problem, it's recommended to set the `b:undo_ftplugin` variable, to a value that resets each option you changed to its default.
For an `indent` plugin, use `b:undo_indent` instead.

Putting it all together, you could have this in `after/indent/rust.vim`:

```
" set options locally
setlocal tabstop=4
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal noexpandtab

" get a pre-existing `undo_indent` variable
let b:undo_ftplugin = get(b:, 'undo_indent', '')

" add a '|' to chain commands if `undo_indent` was set
if ! empty('b:undo_indent')
  let b:undo_indent .= ' | '
endif

" `set option< `restores `option` to its global value
" `.=` appends to the string
let b:undo_indent .=  "setlocal colorcolumn< foldmethod< suffixesadd< path<"
```